# Jenkins pipeline how to get the branch which triggers the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job (not multi-branch pipeline), one of the logic inside my pipeline is, when there is a merge request on the gitlab scm, I want to build something based on the source branch of the merge request which triggered this build.

My question is, inside the Jenkinsfile, how do I dynamically get this source branch and checkout the code and create a workspace for me to run builds on this branch?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the GitLab plugin? If so, when a build is triggered using the webhook it gets access to a few variables.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables

One of them is the branch that triggered the build:

Is `env.gitlabSourceBranch` what you're looking for?